# Getting "D8: " texts in the logs of release build of react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native 0.61.2. When I build the release APK, I get some text with "D8: ". I am unable to understand what does it mean.

Bellow is the log
https://gist.github.com/ElavanResu/9cc4ce051daa1340a4531668e1bc2061

Please help me in understanding this